# Merge Lists where a key in each list is the same

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gin

I have two tables on a postgreSQL table, **products** and **product_variation**. The product_variation contains a **foreign key** populated by the **id** which is a **primary key** for the **products** table. I am trying to make a **GET** request to the api for the Products List that should return each product with all its variation. Example:

```
{
"product": {    "id": 1,
        "name": "iphone14",
        "owner": "admin",
        "price": 50000,
        "description": "Brand New ",
        "imgs_url": [
            "http://cs.com/variation-images/gsmzuydpmgxltpomrdrglhpgjistxlcqubboahkiatcihktrjunihnlutzyvbbnqi14.jpeg",
            "http://cs.com/variation-images/gsmzuydpmgxltpomrdrglhpgjistxlcqubboahkiatcihktrjunihnlutzyvbbnqi14.jpeg"
        ],
        "imgs": [
            "product-images/mlbthlzgvhipftqrwibqwnkcfuywooueavxevnmcwehxvphpbtowxlfrkjpzrmnwapple-iphone-14-pro-max-1.jpg",
            "product-images/vfnkitshpcoiumbeirmcehsiibciwihmaehmuhnfjnitcctnfpkvmhpobqwfwebni14.jpeg"
        ],
        "created_at": "2022-09-26T12:43:41.795886Z"
    },
"variations": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "size": "45",
        "color": "black",
        "img_url": "http://cs.com/variation-images/jxmhzbbfktqtqmzomgxtnallmnhphttyomqcaifecodguwdmwzvnhxeefdkedtfgi14.jpeg",
        "img_name": "variation-images/jxmhzbbfktqtqmzomgxtnallmnhphttyomqcaifecodguwdmwzvnhxeefdkedtfgi14.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "product_id": 1,
        "size": "46",
        "color": "blue",
        "img_url": "http://cs.com/variation-images/gsmzuydpmgxltpomrdrglhpgjistxlcqubboahkiatcihktrjunihnlutzyvbbnqi14.jpeg",
        "img_name": "variation-images/gsmzuydpmgxltpomrdrglhpgjistxlcqubboahkiatcihktrjunihnlutzyvbbnqi14.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "product_id": 2,
        "size": "50",
        "color": "gree",
        "img_url": "http://cs.com/variation-images/qqdihiumlddjqnoppfmzzmgouttdafpoqfqvujhtrznayodabzpmpxktxzkrvfaji14.jpeg",
        "img_name": "variation-images/qqdihiumlddjqnoppfmzzmgouttdafpoqfqvujhtrznayodabzpmpxktxzkrvfaji14.jpeg"
    }
]
}
```

I have tried various sql Queries but they either give me a mixed result where each product_variation duplicates the product or a list of all the products, and a list of all the variations. Please how do i achieve this function.

```
-- name: ListPWV :many //This only lists the products
-- name: ListProducts :many
SELECT *
FROM products
ORDER BY id;


-- name: ListVariations :many
SELECT *
FROM product_variation
ORDER BY id;

type FinalList struct {
    ID          int64           `json:"id"`
    Name        string          `json:"name"`
    Owner       string          `json:"owner"`
    Price       decimal.Decimal `json:"price"`
    Description string          `json:"description"`
    ImgsUrl     []string        `json:"imgs_url"`
    ImgsName    []string        `json:"imgs_name"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    Variation ProductVariation  `json:"variation"`
}


type ProductVariation struct {
    ID        int64  `json:"id"`
    ProductID int64  `json:"product_id"`
    Size      string `json:"size"`
    Color     string `json:"color"`
    ImgUrl    string `json:"img_url"`
    ImgName   string `json:"img_name"`
}
```

Now the main get function:

```
func (server *Server) listProductsWithVariation(ctx *gin.Context) {
    products, err := server.store.ListProducts(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, errorResponse(err))
        return
    }

    var prodVar []FinalList

    for i, prods := range products {
        prodsItems := db.Product{
            Name:        prods.Name,
            Price:       prods.Price,
            Description: prods.Description,
            Owner:       prods.Owner,
            ImgsUrl:     prods.ImgsUrl,
            ImgsName:    prods.ImgsName,
            CreatedAt:   prods.CreatedAt,
        }
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, prodsItems)
        pv, err := server.store.ListVariations(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            if pqErr, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
                switch pqErr.Code.Name() {
                case "foreign_key_violation", "unique_violation":
                    ctx.JSON(http.StatusForbidden, errorResponse(err))
                    return

                }
            }
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }
        if prods.ID == pv[i].ProductID {
        prodVar = append(prodVar, pv[i])}
        
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, pv)
    }
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, products)
}
```

I get an error on the pv **cannot use pv[i] (variable of type db.ProductVariation) as FinalList value in argument to append**

Please how do i solve this issue?
How do i achieve the above json?